# Editing MainWindow.xib

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've been following tutorials and noticed that we always edit ViewController.xib but never touch MainWindow.Xib.  I was wondering why that is. Would there ever be any reason to edit this file?

Answer (score 0):

When an application starts, the startup code looks in the Info.plist of the app for NSMainNibFile key, loads the specified *.xib and the application proceeds from there. The templates in Xcode are set up so that the MainWindow.xib contains an instance of the application delegate which then in turn gets its application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method called.

So the MainWindow.xib really serves as a starting point for your application.

Depending on which Xcode template you used, the MainWindow.xib also contains an instance of your ViewController, so if you want to show a different ViewController as your root view controller than the one created by the project template, you would edit it for that.